# Setting html5 data attributes in vuejs not working

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to add a data attribute to a anchor tag using Vue. And I must be missing something trivial...

I've done what I think I should be doing and this is my template:

```
<template>
    <a :class="entityStates.switch['switch.' + switchName].state === 'on' ? 'active ' : ''"
       v-bind:data-name="entityStates.switch['switch.' + switchName].friendly_name"
       @click.prevent="changeSwitch('switch.' + switchName, $event)"
       class="button small-button d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
       href="#"
       v-if="entityStates !== null">
        <component :is="icon" :size="30"></component>
        <!--        <{{ icon }}-icon title="" :size="30"></{{ icon }}-icon>-->
    </a>
</template>
```

But I don't get any `data-name` attribute when the component is rendered. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you provide the entityStates code (the data structure)?

Comment: That was all it took.. I forgot one level in my ```entityStates```.